# Canvas coordinates changed with jquery

Tags: jquery, canvas

```
//JQUERY
    d = $("#gpart");
    w = 512; h = 326;
    d.width(w);
    d.height(h);
    $ctx = d[0].getContext("2d");
    $ctx.beginPath();
    $ctx.moveTo(100, 0);
    $ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
    $ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    $ctx.strokeStyle = '#bbbbbb';
    $ctx.stroke();
})
//PLAIN
    d = document.getElementById("gpart");
    d.width = 512;
    d.height = 326;
    ctx = d.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(100, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#bbbbbb';
    ctx.stroke();
```

With jquery the coordinates are scaled up by the bigger than standard canvas size (e.g 100 => 170+). Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** In the second example, d is the canvas element, so you set its width and height. In the first example d[0] is the actual canvas element, you should set width and height for d[0].
Check out the working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/2jsSw/

**Old:**
It all goes fine, and the two versions will be the same, if, in the jQuery version, insead of:

```
d.width(w);
d.height(h);
```

(these will set the css width and height of the canvas, in pixels)

you use:

```
d.attr('width',w);
d.attr('height',h);
```

It seems that for the canvas element, the width and height attribute specify the size of the coordinate system used by the canvas API, while the CSS width and height specify the size of the canvas element drawn on the page.